# Copying subset of YAML text into separate file is followed by syntax error while processing

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible, yaml, jenkins-groovy

I am working on a [Jenkins pipeline - YAML - ansible] combination.
In the pipeline, there is an input section, and it looks somewhat like this:

```
student_input = input(
message: 'Input Student details', parameters: [text(defaultValue: 
'''---
student: 
  ID: 100
  grade: 5
  info: 
    email: abc@xyz.com
    home_town: efg
    marks: 
      math: 95
      science: 92
''',
description: '', 
name: 'student'
 )]
)
```

I am then writing this input into a variable using ***readYaml file: "File.yml"*** utility.

In the implementation for this, nested maps with map.each loops have been used to reach the ***info*** and then the ***marks*** section.

Groovy maps code example:

```
value.each { k, v ->

           sh """
           echo '$k: $v' >> student.yml
           """
           }
```

Using this, I am trying to write the entire ***value*** part of the ***info*** section into a separate YAML file, later to be used along with the **include_vars** module of ansible.

While running the groovy pipeline, I am faced with the following problem in Ansible:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.
The error appears to have been in 'True': line 9, column 26, 
but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.(could not open file to display line)"}
```

When I checked the final YAML file, the marks section looks something like this:

```
marks: [math:95, science:92]
```

The way these list elements are written( without whitespace after the colon ) into the file, seems to be causing the error.

Please help me with a solution for this.
Am I missing something, or doing something wrong?

Comment: Why not construct a Map and pass it to `writeYaml`: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writeyaml-write-a-yaml-from-an-object?

Comment: The whitespace is most likely not the root problem. Can you show the whole YAML output?